# Event Callback Inside Template Literal

Tags: javascript, template-literals

Hi everyone I'm new to javascript and I'm trying to execute a callback function on the user's click event using template literals. However the callback is being executed on the template's evaluation.

The row method is called by another class which is passing the item and the callback function.

```js
class Clazz {
  row(item, deleteCallback){
      return `<a href="#" onClick="${deleteCallback(item.requestId)}"></a>`
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: `deleteCallback(item.requestedId)` is a function invocation, not a function reference, which event handlers expect.  `${}` is going to execute whatever is inside it.

Comment: But maybe the invocation returns a function ;)

Comment: Entirely possible, except that wouldn't match the first paragraph issue statement, ^_^

Comment: I guess the question is how is the result of `row()` used?  Because you're trying to stick a callback function variable into html, turning it into text to be parsed into html.  My gut is saying to just create an `a` tag and `addEventListener` on it with the method, but whatever uses `row()` may expect a string as a response

Comment: @Taplar Inline event listeners, which this is, don’t expect a function reference. They simply expect an arbitrary block of JS. Inline event listeners are bad practice though.

Comment: True, since inline bindings do the whole wrapping in an anonymous function or whatever they do, the expression could be anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a better approach to what you're trying to achieve is to return an element from `row` instead of an HTML string. Like so:

```
class Clazz {
  row(item, deleteCallback){
    const a  = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = '#';
    a.onclick = () => deleteCallback(item.requestId);
    return a;
  }
}
```

This could then be added to the DOM using `append`, `after` or something similar.